# Stop button nested inside a form from submitting and have it fire a different function

Tags: reactjs

I have a close button nested inside a form that is supposed to reset the form and close the popup modal the form is sitting on.

I've changed the button type from the default submit to type='reset' and have an onClick that is supposed to fire my resetting/closing function, but the function is never being called and instead the submit function is called.

is that not possible with jsx or what am I missing?

(Note that Button is just a component wrapping a `<button>` html tag)

```
import Button from '../../../components/Button'

    export const SomeForm = (props) => (
      <form className='quote-form__wrapper' onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <Button
          className='close-btn'
          type='reset'
          onClick={props.resetForm}
          value='CLOSE' text='x' />

        some form fields...

        <Button
          className='btn ripple-btn'
          type='submit'
          text={props.btnText} />
      </form>
    )
```

**EDIT:**

I should add that when I don't use a custom Button component to render the button element it does work even though I don't change the button type the right function (resetForm) is being called:

```
const someForm = (props) => (
  <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
    <div>
      <button className='close-btn' onClick={props.resetForm} value='CLOSE'>
        x
      </button>

      some form fields...

      <button
        className='ripple-btn btn'
        type='submit'>
        {props.btnText}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form> 
)
```

For what it's worth the Button component looks like this:

```
const Button = (props) => (
  <button className={props.className} {...props.attributes}>
    {props.text}
  </button>
  )

export default Button
```

Comment: What if you remove the the onClick from the form?

Comment: You mean un-nest the element so the close button is sitting outside of the form?

Comment: Sorry I meant the button.

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing down the other props properly in your Button component. You should use `{...props}` and not `{...props.attributes}`.

```
const Button = (props) => (
  <button className={props.className} {...props}>
    {props.text}
  </button>
);

export default Button;
```

Any props that you don't want to pass directly to the `button` could be obtained from the props using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
const Button = ({text, className, ...props}) => (
  <button className={className} {...props}>
    {text}
  </button>
);
```